# Cocoa MVC restrictions

Tags: cocoa, model-view-controller, design-patterns, cocoa-design-patterns

In Cocoa MVC adoption, View knows nothing about the Model, which illustrated in this diagram:

[image: Cocoa MVC interaction diagram]

But consider this example:
I have **Item** class in my model and I want visual representation for it. Most obvious for me is **ItemView** class, which is initialized with **Item**.
So, in this way, I'm breaking Cocoa MVC rules and feeling uncomfortable with it. But, I'm feeling uncomfortable also not having class like **ItemView**. What is the most practical solution?

Comment: It doesnt mean you all the time have Item, ItemView, ItemViewController, ItemController etc....

Comment: For me, Item and ItemView is very frequent situation.

Comment: Your ItemView is usaully subclass of ??

Comment: ItemView most of the time is composite view, which has as child views UIImageView's, UILabel's and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are really concerned about MVC, what about defining a method in your controller like:

```
- (UIView*)itemViewForItem:(Item*)item;
```

which is responsible for creating and "populating" your ItemView?

You main controller class would then act as a controller both for your main view and all `ItemViews` you have got.

Another approach would be giving each ItemView its own ItemViewController. This is perfectly fine and if your controller/view is of any complexity, IMO, also the best approach. The drawback with this is that dealing with controllers container is supported only on iOS>5.

Comment: If I have not only ItemView, but also EmployeeView and CustomerView on one screen - controller becomes god object, which, in my opinion, is worse than breaking Cocoa MVC rules.

Comment: Yeah, that is the case for separate controllers: ItemViewControllers, EmployeeViewController, etc. If you want to follow MVC, that is the way. On the other hand, I understand you are using custom views: think that you could be using standard `UIView` and "custom" controllers to the same effect.

Comment: btw, I am not saying that your design is bad. I think there are cases when breaking a little the rules is ok. I have been just trying to explain how IMO you could deal with MVC without breaking any rules (and don't forget that this has definitely a drawback on iOS<5, so your solution might be better on that account).

Comment: I think we should forgot iOS<5 time. Thank you, I will follow your advice about nested ViewControllers in future.